# this.props.state not defined fast enough? redux/react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

I've been trying to just filter and access a user from the state tree. the redux devtools shows that its in StoreFront component but it keeps saying that this.props.user is undefined. now i tried to console.log it and realized its defined after the component renders a few times. its just complicated and i need some guidance.

heres the reducer

```
import { GET_USER } from '../actions/types';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';


const initialState = {
  users: [
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'joe',
      email: 'joeiscool@gmail.com',
      password :'joe6969'
    },
    {
      id: uuidv4(),
      name: 'sally',
      email: 'joeishunky@gmail.com',
      password :'bigbooty45678'
    }
  ]
}


export default function(state = initialState, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case GET_USER:
     return {
       user: state.users.filter(user => user.id !== action.payload)
     }
     default:
       return state;
  }
};
```

the StoreFront component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, Button, Container, Row } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getProducts } from '../actions/productActions';
import { getUser } from '../actions/userActions';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Storefront extends Component {
 componentDidMount() {
   this.props.getProducts();
   this.props.getUser(2);

 }

  render(){
    const { products } = this.props.product;
    const { user } = this.props.user;
    return(
      <div style={productDisplayStyle}>
          <Container style={{justifyContent: 'center'}}>
           <Row style={{justifyContent: 'space-around'}}>
            {products.map(({ id, info, price, img}) => (
              <Card style={{ width: '18rem', border: 'none',padding:'5px'  }} key={id}>
                 <Card.Img variant="top" src={img} className='productImg'/>
                 <Card.Body>
                   <Card.Title>{user.name}</Card.Title>
                   <Card.Text>
                     {info}
                   </Card.Text>
                   <Card.Text style={{fontSize: '30px'}}>{price}</Card.Text>
                   <Button variant='info'>Add To Cart!</Button>
                 </Card.Body>
             </Card>
            ))}

          </Row>
        </Container>
    </div>
    )
  }
}

const productDisplayStyle =
  {
    width: '90%',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    margin:'auto',
    padding: '5px'
  }

Storefront.propTypes = {
  getProducts: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  product: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  getUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  user: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  product: state.product,
  user: state.user
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getProducts, getUser })(Storefront);
```

if you need any other info let me know. i just really need some help

Answer (score 3):

You have wrong destructuring syntax. You're trying to access the properties one level too deep.

Change

```
const { products } = this.props.product;
const { user } = this.props.user;
```

to

```
const {products, user} = this.props
```

**EDIT**

I recommend getting rid of `GET_USER` all together and making an action that will set your "active user". This is just for inspiration, I don't know the use case of your app. Also take a look at [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect), this would perfectly fit your usecase.

I'll provide a working example, edit to your needs ...

First make an action where the argument is the ID of the user that you want to set as active. Call it `setActiveUserById`

Then add this code to your reducer. Notice that I used `find` instead of `filter`. the find() method returns the **value** of the **first element** in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.

```
export default function(state = initialState, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case SET_ACTIVE_USER_BY_ID:
    return {
      ...state,
      activeUser: state.users.find(user => user.id === action.activeUserId)
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

In your component set the active user

replace

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.getProducts();
  this.props.getUser(2);
}
```

with

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.getProducts();
  this.props.setActiveUserById(2);
}
```

Then replace `mapStateToProps` with this

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  product: state.product,
  activeUser: state.activeUser
})
```

and

```
const {products, activeUser} = this.props
```

And now instead of using `user.name` use `activeUser.name`

Comment: thank you i got it to not break, but user.name is still undefined. if i console.log user an array comes back but i expected this to be an object. it'll console.log the array of both users at first then console.log just the one user as an array

Comment: I think you're confusing a couple things. Why do you expect user to be an object? `user: state.users.filter(user => user.id !== action.payload)` the filter function returns an array not an object. The reducer is not meant to be used as a selector for your data, if you want to get a specific user(s) I recommend looking into [redux reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) or filtering directly in your component instead. The state also won't have users as a property after calling `GET_USER` more than once, since you're only returning the state with one property `user`.

Comment: hey sorry but i got it to work but it doesn't define activeUser fast enough it says its undefined it crashes the app. if i console.log activeUser in the return its undefined two times then the user is logged

Comment: You can render either the whole component optionally or only the part where you're rendering the name by using `{activeUser?.name && <Card.Title>{activeUser.name}</Card.Title>}`